# tikz externalize optimizes pictures away although jobname complies

Tags: tikz-external, jobname

I used tikz externalize successfully for a time now. But since my pc crashed once the externalized pictures are instantly deleted. Reading the manual I found out, that they are "optimized away" because of the jobname differing of the documents (?) jobname. I did not change anything here. How can I fix that?

Here's the log of the main tex-file:

http://pastebin.com/zW60UZgH

Comment: The log pretty much says it all, you have `optimize=\false` where it should have been `optimize=false`. If they were already externalised then this is also why it worked before, it found the image and never came to this code.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong log. Now I changed it to the log of the main tex-file without using the optimizer=false tag. Firstly because I don't want to use it and it didn't work either. And externalizing worked well: to update a specific picture I removed it or used "tikzexternalizedisable".

Comment: It is not clear from the log where the error lies, however, it clearly states that the externalised objects are errorneous. Please supply: `bilder/ext/diplom-figure3.log` or any of the other externalised images, they contain the error.

Comment: Just guessing but did you register/ sync your dropbox folder recently after the crash? Looks like a system problem instead of LaTeX related...

Comment: After investigating I tracked down the problem to the following code:

    `\begin{enumerate}
     \item "\`asdf"'
    \end{enumerate}`

Seems like this interferes with shell-escape tikz-externalize uses. (Not allowed to answer my own question, although this is the solution. So someone could answer this :-))

Comment: ok, escaping works, but that was the mistake: `\end{enumerate}\\ `

Comment: You should add a minimal example to your question; as it stands it's impossible to give a real solution and it can't be upvoted so that you can get reputation sufficient for a self-answer.